# How to get max length of each column in unix?

Tags: unix, awk

Suppose, I have a source file like this.

```
ID|NAME|ADDRESS
1|ABC|PUNE
2|XYZA|MUMBAI
12|VB|NAGPUR
```

I want to get the maximum length of each column (excluding the header names).
Output should be like this.
    2|4|6

I have tried the command like this. 
     tail +2 filename | cut -d"|" -f1 | awk '{ print length }' | sort -r | uniq

This works for 1st column. Is there any option available in awk to get max length for each column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be a general way to do it, so that you don't have to care about the number of fields you have: store the lengths in an array and keep checking if it is the maximum or not. Finally, loop through them and print the results.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) max[i]=(length($i)>max[i]?length($i):max[i])}
           END {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d%s", max[i], (i==NF?RS:FS)}' file
```

See output:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) max[i]=(length($i)>max[i]?length($i):max[i])} END {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d%s", max[i], (i==NF?RS:FS)}' a
2|4|6
```

For variable number of columns, we can store the maximum amount of columns in for example `cols`:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{cols=(cols<=NF?NF:cols); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) max[i]=(length($i)>max[i]?length($i):max[i])} END {for (i=1; i<=cols; i++) printf "%d%s", max[i], (i==cols?RS:FS)}' a
2|4|6
```

Comment: @fedorqui That might print correct output if every line has the same number of fields, what if the last line misses one?

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai if so, we can store the maximum NF and loop based on that. See update.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (but if there are many fields I'd use `for` cycle and an array to store the length of fields...):

```
awk -F '|' 'NR>1 {if ( length($1) > l1 ) { l1=length($1) }
                  if ( length($2) > l2 ) { l2=length($2) }
                  if ( length($3) > l2 ) { l3=length($3) }
                 }
             END { print l1 "|" l2 "|" l3 }' INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654092/1429450), this can be parallelized with [GNU Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel):

`longest.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}

NR>1 {
    len = length($col)
    if (len > max) {
        max = len
        maxline = $col
    }
    if (len < min) {
        min = len
        minline = $col
    }
}

END {
    printf "%-8d: %-8d %-8s  %-8d %-8s\n", col, max, maxline, min, minline
}
```

```bash
# Find longest (shortest) fields
#
# usage:

awk -v col=3 -f longest.awk my.csv

# returns: field-length data for column #3
#
# can be parallelized with GNU Parallel

parallel awk -v col={} -f longest.awk my.csv ::: `seq 64`

# where 64 is the number of columns in the CSV file.
```