# Vertically divide an array so we get minimum splits

Tags: algorithm

I am thinking on the following problem.

I can have an array of strings like

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
aa     aa      aa      aa  
aaa    aaa     aaaaa   aaa 
aaaa   aaaaaaa aa      a   
...........................
```

Actually it is `CSV` file. And I should find a way to divide this vertically into one or more files. Condition for splitting is that no one file contain no row that exceeds some bytes. For simplicity we can rewrite that array with lengths:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
2      2       2       2   
3      3       5       3   
4      7       2       1   
...........................
```

And let's say the limit is `10`, i.e. if `> 9` we should split. So if we split into 2 files `[Col1, Col2, Col3]` and `[Col4]` this will not satisfy the condition because the first file will contain `3 + 3 + 5 > 9` in the second row and `4 + 7 + 2 > 9` in the third row. If we split into `[Col1, Col2]` and `[Col3, Col4]` this will not satisfy the condition because the first file will contain `4 + 7 > 9` in the third row. So we are splitting this into 3 files like `[Col1]`, `[Col2, Col3]` and `[Col4]`. Now every file is correct and looks like:

```
File1 | File2          | File3
------------------------------
Col1  |  Col2    Col3  |  Col4 
2     |  2       2     |  2    
3     |  3       5     |  3    
4     |  7       2     |  1    
...............................
```

So it should split from left to right giving maximum columns as possible to the left file. The problem is that this file can be huge and I don't want to read it into memory and so we read the initial file line by line and somehow I should determine a set of indexes to split. If that is possible at all? I hope I described the problem well, so you can understand it.

Comment: columns can be swapped?

Comment: How many columns are, and rows?

Comment: Up to 2,500 columns and up to 10,000 rows. In the future can be even more. Columns can not be swapped, moved etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generally awk is quite good at handling large csv files.

You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653785/how-to-get-max-length-of-each-column-in-unix) to retrieve the max length for each column and then decide how to split.

Let's say the file.txt contains

```
Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4
aa;aa;aa;aa
aaa;aaa;aaaaa;aaa
aaaa;aaaaaaa;aa;a
```

(Assuming windows style quotes) Running the following :

```
> awk -F";" "NR>1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) max[i]=(length($i)>max[i]?length($i):max[i])} END {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf \"%d%s\", max[i], (i==NF?RS:FS)}" file.txt
```

Will output :

```
4;7;5;3
```

Could you try this on your real data set ?

Comment: Only with the max values for each columns you can't find optimal solution.

Comment: And what does this give me? I can not make a decision from `4;7;5;3`, can I?

Comment: 4;7;5;3 tells you that you can combine columns 1 and 3 because `4+5<=9`
then you solve 9;7;3 which you cannot reduce according to your rules so three files : (1;3)(2)(4).

Comment: Knowing that you can split your file with awk : `awk "{print $1 $3}" file_1.txt; awk "{print $2}" file_2.txt; awk "{print $4}" file_3.txt`

Comment: In OP example the max values of each column aren't at the same row, his solution in fact is different.

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca what do you mean by optimal solution ? EDIT : ok I got it.

Comment: Suppose that `3` of the last column was a `9`, the solution is still dividing in 3 columns, but using only we maximums values `4;7;5;9` have to be divide into `4` columns.

Comment: In fact given 4;7;5;9 I would break it in three files : (4;5)(7)(9)

Comment: I'm assuming that swaps columns isn't valid, but  the same happens if `4` was a `5`: `5;7;5;9`

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca I agree it's not optimal, the worst case in my mind would be some kind of limit * Identity matrix where the diagonal consists only of 9. I would split each columns whereas the file is valid.

Comment: I think you are thinking in wrong direction. It is not about optimal. Think of it like we are creating the first file. Take first column. Take second column and see if we break the condition. If we break, the first file consists of only first column. If not , take third column etc.